# Loading 10000 images in listbox or listview with 3 columns in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, listbox

Loading 10000 images in listbox or listview in 3 columns now i am referring [Async Data Binding & Data Virtualization](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/749212/WPF-Async-Data-Binding-Data-Virtualization)

but it is very helpful in 1 column if adding 3 columns to the same project it load the images from bottom to top. it take 5 to 7 sec to load all images to listview.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListImageDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type Model:FileInformation}">
        <VirtualizingStackPanel  Orientation="Vertical"  IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="230" Height="230">
                <Border Padding="5" Margin="10" BorderBrush="Orange">
                    <Image Stretch="Fill"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                        <Image.Source>
                            <PriorityBinding>
                                <Binding Path="FastBitmap"></Binding>
                                <Binding Converter="{StaticResource InstantiatePropertyAsyncConverterKey}"></Binding>
                            </PriorityBinding>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>

                </Border>

                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Black" Opacity="0.70" Width="200">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileInfo.Name}" Foreground="White" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </VirtualizingStackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

    <ListView  Name="lstBox1" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ImageGalleryItemsPanelTemplate}" ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListImageDataTemplate}}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ImageList}"  Margin="0,10,18,-10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

If I remove

```
ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ImageGalleryItemsPanelTemplate}"
```

from the listview, it loads images in 1 column and works fine but adding 3 column by using ImageGalleryItemsPanelTemplate

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ImageGalleryItemsPanelTemplate">
        <UniformGrid Columns="3"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></UniformGrid>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How should anyone help you if you won't tell us the problem? ;)
Is anything not working or is it just to slow? How fast should it be?

Comment: I think the problem is clear. Virtualization works for 1 column, For more than 1 columns it doesn't.

Comment: it is working but loading the images from bottom listviewitem to top listviewitem . i need to load images from top to bottom or images should load while scrolling

Comment: @Manjunath can you paste the code for 1 column and 3 columns to look for the differences>

Comment: is there any way to archive this problem @ Peuczyński

Comment: if i remove this in listbox ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ImageGalleryItemsPanelTemplate}" it works in 1 column.                                 <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ImageGalleryItemsPanelTemplate">
            <UniformGrid Columns="3"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>